# Roots of square equation, the solution for the value of element K in a series of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, integers

I'm facing an informatics problem, math based.

Having this series:

```
1,  1, 2,  1, 2, 3,  1, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ....
```

i have to efficiently find the value of element from position K;

for example, on position `k = 5`, element has the `value 2`

**the way to solve this** is to solve a square equation like this:

```
x^2 - x - 2*i
```

where `i` stands from `k-1 to 1` and we downgrade `k` until we find a solution which satisfies this:

- one root of the equation is `higher than 0`
- it's a natural number

and the value of that element on position `k` will be `k-i`
i did that on C++ and works 100%, with help from a friend;

for example, when k = 5 and our `i` iterator gets the value 3, the equation will be:

```
x^2 - x - 6
```

with positive root `x1 = 3`
and in final, the solution will be `k-i` -> `5-3` which is clearly `2`, the value of the element from position `K`

i am trying to understand this for hours, but i dont get why the solution of that equation gives us the value from position K

if anybody knows the answer, i'm waiting for it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mon Feb 20 11:57:46 PST 2017
    1    1        1    1
    2    1        1    1
    3    2        2    3
    4    1        2    3
    5    2        2    3
    6    3        3    6
    7    1        3    6
    8    2        3    6
    9    3        3    6
   10    4        4   10
   11    1        4   10
   12    2        4   10
   13    3        4   10
   14    4        4   10
   15    5        5   15
   16    1        5   15
   17    2        5   15
   18    3        5   15
   19    4        5   15
   20    5        5   15
   21    6        6   21
   22    1        6   21
   23    2        6   21
   24    3        6   21
   25    4        6   21
```

========================================================

```
  system("date");

  for(int k = 1; k <= 25; ++k) 
  {
    int q = IntSqrt( 1 + 8 * k)  ;
    int n = ( q - 1) / 2 ;
    int t = n * ( n+1) / 2;
    int val = k - t;
    if( val == 0 )   val +=  n;
    cout << setw(5) << k  << setw(5) << val  << "    " << setw(5) << n  << setw(5) << t  << endl; 

  }

  system("date");
```

============================================

The [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) are
$$ 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21,  $$
and by formula
$$  T_n = \frac{n^2 + n}{2} $$
Your description says that the entry at position $k =T_n$ is $n$ itself. The next several entries are then $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, n, n+1.$

So, the first task is to (correctly!) find the largest $n$ such that
$$ T_n  = \frac{n^2 + n}{2}   \leq k.  $$ Then, if $T_n= k,$ the entry is $n.$ If $k > T_n$ but $k < T_{n+1},$ the entry is
$$ k - T_n  $$

All you need, as a separate item, is a C++ function that gives a **correct** value for
$$  \lfloor \sqrt w \rfloor $$
when $w > 0$ is an integer. We want
$$ n^2 + n - 2 k \leq 0,   $$
$$ 4n^2 + 4n - 8 k \leq 0,   $$
$$ 4n^2 + 4n + 1 - 1 - 8 k \leq 0,   $$
$$ 4n^2 + 4n + 1 \leq 1 + 8 k,   $$
$$ (2n+1)^2 \leq 1 + 8 k,   $$
$$ 2n+1 \leq \sqrt { 1 + 8 k},   $$
$$ 2n \leq -1 + \sqrt { 1 + 8 k},   $$
$$ n \leq  \frac{ -1 + \sqrt { 1 + 8 k}}{2}.   $$
$$ n = \left\lfloor  \frac{ -1 + \sqrt { 1 + 8 k}}{2} \right\rfloor   $$
$$ n = \left\lfloor  \frac{ -1 + \lfloor \sqrt { 1 + 8 k} \rfloor}{2} \right\rfloor   $$

```
int IntSqrt(int i)
{
  // cerr << "called intsqrt  with   " << i << endl;
  if ( i <= 0 ) return 0;
  else if ( i <= 3) return 1;
  else if ( i >= 2147395600) return 46340;
  else
  {
    float r;
    r = 1.0 * i;
    r = sqrt(r);
    int root = (int) ceil(r);
    while ( root * root   <= i ) ++root;
    while ( root * root   > i ) --root;
    return  root ;
  }
} // IntSqrt
```

Comment: uhh, that's a good answer, thanks !
which is the relation between (n^2 + n) / 2 with that series? that's what i'm trying to reach.

Comment: got it! thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @GabiMMinimalART I added a short output at the beginning and  the heart of main()

Comment: i have noticed it :) very well explained